# Nested if queries in patch context NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to change color of patches to green under these conditions:

-IF there are any two blue patches on same column and their distance is smaller than 25 AND

-IF there are any yellow patches on same column and between these selected blue patches

-Then change color of all patches satisfying these conditions to green.

I am struggling to make it in NetLogo, tried using nested loop but couldn't find a way. Thank you for any help. And I have added a sample image which I want to achieve and marked example blue patches.

[image]

As addition, to show what I want to do in code (sorry about code):

```
     if any? patches with [pcolor = blue and
      (if any? patches with [pcolor = blue and pycor = ?(selected_first_blue's_pycor)
        if any? patches with [pcolor = yellow and pycor < ??(selected_first_blue's_pycor) and pycor > ?(selected_second_blue's_pycor)))
    [ask patches [set pcolor green]]
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and explain what it gets wrong.

Comment: Added a code sample, just to show my logic. If it is not suitable NetLogo structure, is there any other way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are approaching it, you need fairly convoluted statements like:

```
let upper-blues patches with [color = blue and
   any? other patches with [color = blue and pxcor = [pxcor] of myself
        and pycor < [pycor] of myself and pycor > [pycor] of myself - 25]
```

I believe this would be much easier to take the perspective of the patch you want to potentially turn green. If I have interpreted your conditions correctly, that patch needs to work out the closest yellow patch above/below/at and then check if there are two blue patches bracketing both the yellow and itself with the blue patches sufficiently close to each other. I assume you have wrapping turned off.

Here is a complete model that puts in a red turtle instead of turning the patch green so you can see whether it is identifying the correct patches.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  ask n-of 100 patches [set pcolor blue]
  ask n-of 100 patches [set pcolor yellow]
end

to convert-to-green
  let turn-green nobody
  ask patches
  [ let my-column patches with [pxcor = [pxcor] of myself]
    let above-yellow min-one-of my-column with [pcolor = yellow and pycor >= [pycor] of myself][pycor]
    let above-blue ifelse-value (above-yellow != nobody) [min-one-of my-column with [pcolor = blue and pycor > [pycor] of above-yellow][pycor]][nobody]
    let below-yellow max-one-of my-column with [pcolor = yellow and pycor <= [pycor] of myself][pycor]
    let below-blue ifelse-value (below-yellow != nobody) [max-one-of my-column with [pcolor = blue and pycor < [pycor] of below-yellow][pycor]][nobody]
    if above-blue != nobody and below-blue != nobody and ([pycor] of above-blue - [pycor] of below-blue < 25)
    [ set turn-green (patch-set self turn-green)
    ]
  ]
  ask turn-green [sprout 1 [set color red]]
end
```

Once you are satisfied it is working correctly, change `ask turn-green [sprout 1 [set color red]]` to `ask turn-green [set pcolor green]`.

This code checks each patch in random order and adds it to the set of patches (called turn-green) if the conditions are satisfied. Once all patches have been tested, the set of selected patches then change their colour. This avoids issues of yellow or blue patches turning green and not being available for later patches to check against.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply and the code. I have tried it, there were missing brackets and added if any? check before each " let" code in "ask patches". However, this time it requires another check for assigned patches inside added checks. For example gives nobody error for "below-yellow" patches in this line: "  if any? patches with [pcolor = blue and pycor < [pycor] of below-yellow]". Also, do you suggest me charging few agents for this task by checking each patch if satisfting conditions or is it better to following patch-context direciton. Also, wrapping is turned off.

Comment: "set turn-green patch-set self turn-green "- Error: Expected a command. Also, same thing happens about conditions which I stated in previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried edited version. I mean it gives error when for example "above-yellow" is empty: "ANY? expected input to be an agentset but got NOBODY instead". I hope I could explain what I mean.

Comment: I could solve it by considering each column one by one and using your "upper, lower" idea. Thank you for your help and time. But I couldn't find the problem with your code which seems can solve problem with few line codes or maybe I couldn't run it. Anyway thanks for help and direction.

Comment: okay, I have done it in a way I can test the code. It seems to work fine (though I did have to fix some brackets)